# Can we regularize/penalize the KNN model?

Tags: regularization, k-nearest-neighbour

While reading through KNN in detail, I was checking if there is a way to improve/penalize KNN?
I didn't find any concrete/easily understandable solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "improve"?

Comment: One way of regularization that I can imagine is in the selection and weighing of the parameters that are used in the model.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. There are many forms of regularization: $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, early stopping, dropout, etc. $k$NN is a nonparametric model, it doesn't have parameters to penalize, drop, or way to stop training earlier.

The main point of regularization is preventing overfitting. The way to prevent overfitting in $k$NN is to increase $k$ as it leads to averaging over many points instead of memorizing the training set as in $k=1$. It also makes the result smoother, because of averaging, which is another common consequence of regularization. A similar approach  is used in decision trees where we restrict depth, minimal node size, or prune them, as means of regularization.

You can also use [penalized distance metrics](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-new-better-version-of-the-k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-12af81391682) and in $k$NN regression more robust aggregation function, e.g. median, to make it less susceptible to outliers.